# How to get a time widget in django forms?

Tags: django

I know we can have date widget in django.

```
birth_year = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES))
```

Is there something similar for selecting time in django?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the DateTime field.

```
birth_time=forms.DateTime()
```

For more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a widget for that? Like my example code automatically writes the markup? Is there something similar to that?

Comment: I don't think there's a built in widget, but a simple google search revealed this snippet. http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1202/